# Grouping with specific attribute in Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Guys I have a asp:listview item.I want to read data from database and want to categorize them like below.
http://prntscr.com/8rhpcb
   For now my codelike below:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
         ItemPlaceholderID="iph" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table id="item_table" border="1">
                <tr style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="SurnameLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Surname") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="SexLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Sex") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AgeLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
           </table>

        </ItemTemplate>

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="table1" runat="server" border="1" 
             style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;
                border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">

                        <th id="Th1" style="width:130px" runat="server">Id</th>
                        <th id="Th2" style="width:130px" runat="server">Name</th>
                        <th id="Th3" style="width:130px" runat="server">Surname</th>
                        <th id="Th4" style="width:130px" runat="server">Sex</th>
                        <th id="Th5" style="width:130px" runat="server">Email</th>
                        <th id="Th6" style="width:130px" runat="server">City</th>
                        <th id="Th7" style="width:130px" runat="server">Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                </tr>
            </table>

            <table id="table2" runat="server" border="1" 
             style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
                        <th id="Th8"  style="width:130px" runat="server">Id</th>
                        <th id="Th9"  style="width:130px" runat="server">Name</th>
                        <th id="Th10" style="width:130px" runat="server">Surname</th>
                        <th id="Th11" style="width:130px" runat="server">Sex</th>
                        <th id="Th12" style="width:130px" runat="server">Email</th>
                        <th id="Th13" style="width:130px" runat="server">City</th>
                        <th id="Th14" style="width:130px" runat="server">Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="iph"></tr>
            </table>

        </LayoutTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

I can do this with using 2 listview But I want to do it in 1 listview.It can possible?If it is possible can you explain me with detail or with code example?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the pic, it just open a blank page

Comment: I edited it.Please help me if you know how to do is in 1 listview?

Comment: @harunyılmaz - `Repeater` control will best suit this requirement.

Comment: I can see it now, and Rahul suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: yeah I tried it and it is easy to do with Repeater .I challenged myself to do with listview.Finally I find the answer below.Thanks by the way your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the way to do this.Code is below:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
         ItemPlaceholderID="iph" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table id="item_table" border="1">

                <%# AddTitle() %>
                <tr style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="SurnameLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Surname") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="SexLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Sex") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AgeLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
           </table>

        </ItemTemplate>

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="table1" runat="server" border="1" 
             style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
                        <th id="Th1" style="width:130px" runat="server">Id</th>
                        <th id="Th2" style="width:130px" runat="server">Name</th>
                        <th id="Th3" style="width:130px" runat="server">Surname</th>
                        <th id="Th4" style="width:130px" runat="server">Sex</th>
                        <th id="Th5" style="width:130px" runat="server">Email</th>
                        <th id="Th6" style="width:130px" runat="server">City</th>
                        <th id="Th7" style="width:130px" runat="server">Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="iph">

                </tr>
            </table>

        </LayoutTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

and in code behind:

```
string lastvalue = "";
    protected string AddTitle() {

        string newvalue = Eval("Sex").ToString();

        if (newvalue != lastvalue)
        {
            lastvalue = newvalue;
            return String.Format("<tr class=" + "group" + "><td colspan=" + "7" + ">Gender:{0}</td></tr>", newvalue);
        }
        else {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

first of all,For grouping data like the pic, data records must be ordered.After that in AddTitle method every time getting record from database,it controls the gender type if it is different from previous gender type,it adds a column to table like "Men list" or "Women List".I hope it will help the others who have problems like me.